# Connecting MacBook air to a Samsung monitor using a thunderbolt

Tags: display, thunderbolt

I own MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2015), I bought a Samsung C24F396FHU 24 inch monitor to use a bigger screen and prevent headache. But now that I connected the laptop to the monitor using a Thunderbolt to HDMI cable , the font is not smooth at all and the text is not as readable as it used to be on the original display.

[image]
The cable:
[image]
Is the issue due to using non-Apple product (Samsung monitor)?

The monitor is FHD 1920x1080 and there's not much settings to adjust the resolution (picture below).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use a Samsung or (almost) any monitor with a Mac.  You don't have to use Apple monitors.

1. What does "1028" mean?   What is the native resolution of the monitor?  For example it might be FHD 1920x1080 or 1280x1024 or 4K etc.   If you don't know then what is the make and model?
2. If possible, connect your monitor to another computer or to a TV device like a Roku, cable box, etc to see if the monitor works nicely with those or if it shows the same problems with any device, in which case it might be defective.
3. Go into System Preferences --> Displays and see that the resolution is set to "Default for Display".   The preferences tool may look like one of the following.   Note I have not chosen "Default for Display" for one of my monitors .... but you SHOULD choose it as a starting point to get the best results.
   [image]

Comment: Sorry it was a typo! I meant FHD 1920x1080. and I've chosen the option "best for the so called monitor". I must try connecting it to another laptop or PC to see if the problem persists.

Comment: That resolution is about as low as you get on a computer monitor of that size. I've got a Dell 24" monitor at 1920 by 1200 because the 1080 variants were just not as sharp and clear. Also the Mac probably has a higher resolution than that even at a smaller physical size, if you have a the retina version. Adding the Mac model to your question would help.

Comment: A 24" HD res monitor should look a LOT better than the pictures you posted.    What model is your Mac and exactly how are you cabling it?   Which port connected to which port by what cables and adapters?

Comment: @SteveChambers, I edited my question and added the requested information.

Answer (score 1):

Did you manage to resolve this? If so could you post your solution? I'm in the same position as you and would like to know if this can be resolved.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/333457)

Comment: The problem was the cable (thunderbolt) that didn't support 4k resolution, it was HD! So I bought another cable which was 4k and got a clear font and display.